# svnX - adding filename with @ character

Tags: svn

I find that I cannot add files having the @ character in their names when using svnX.
How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I was using version 0.9.13. The latest version from https://code.google.com/p/svnx/downloads/list does not have this issue.